# Execute elastic search query in java code

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to execute following query in my java code.How can I do this in java?

> GET /_mapping/explore

Comment: Can you please add the Error message you are getting with this code before you ask for the direct solution ?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a library that implements  JAX-RS, such as Jersey. You can also consume REST services with Spring.

Answer (score 1):

What if you have something like this:

```
if (query != null) {
     URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:9200/_mapping/explore");
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
     connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
     BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine;
     StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

     while ((inputLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
           response.append(inputLine);
     }
     return new JSONObject(response.toString());
}
```

The above is just a sample for you to reproduce. Hope it helps!